# Composer PHPSpreadsheet gives error for gd extension eventhough its enabled

Tags: php, composer-php, phpspreadsheet

PHP Version 5.6.25
Extension enabled PHP_Gd2

Downloaded PHPSpreadsheet-develop zip file from GitHub.
extracted this file to the project folder c:\wamp\project.

While running below command from the project folder:

```
composer require phpoffice/phpspreadsheet
```

Getting following error:
Can someone help me with the error below?

```
Using version ^1.2 for phpoffice/phpspreadsheet
./composer.json has been created
Loading composer repositories with package information
Updating dependencies (including require-dev)
Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

Problem 1
- phpoffice/phpspreadsheet 1.2.1 requires ext-gd * -> the requested PHP 
extension gd is missing from your system.
- phpoffice/phpspreadsheet 1.2.0 requires ext-gd * -> the requested PHP 
extension gd is missing from your system.
- Installation request for phpoffice/phpspreadsheet ^1.2 -> satisfiable by 
phpoffice/phpspreadsheet[1.2.0, 1.2.1].

To enable extensions, verify that they are enabled in your .ini files:
- C:\php\php.ini
You can also run php --ini inside terminal to see which files are used by 
PHP in CLI mode.

Installation failed, deleting ./composer.json.
```

I have verified that php gd2 extension is enabled as follows:

- to verify whether gd2 extension is enabled I manually checked php.ini file windows extension section and it shows that gd2 extension is enabled. "extension=php_gd2.dll".
- Checked using phpinfo() it shows that gd2 extension is enabled

The most surprising thing is same composer command run on 1 PC where PHP version is 5.6.35 and giving error as above in another PC where PHP version is 5.6.25. Does it have to do anything with version? As per requirement of PHPSpreadsheet it should work for PHP version 5.6 or newer.

Comment: If php claims that the extension is not enabled, then it is not enabled. Something with your attempt went wrong. Check `phpinfo()` for confirmation if you like. To answer your question you will need to post the lines you used to enable the extension here in the question.

Comment: Side note: again and again we see that people are frustrated and annoyed when trying to install components in MS-Windows. Since that system still has no working software management which takes care of such things they are left alone and bound to fail. Why is it that Microsoft appears to be unable to copycat such an approach? It has stolen so many other ideas and solutions, why not that one which offers so many benefits on other operating systems? Or asked the other way 'round: why do people still use MS-Windows despite all its shortcomings?

Comment: @arkascha, to verify whether gd2 extension is enabled I manually checked php.ini file windows extension section and it shows that gd2 extension is enabled. "extension=php_gd2.dll". The most surprising thing is same composer command run on 1 PC where PHP version is 5.6.35 and giving error as above in another PC where PHP version is 5.6.25. It has to do anything with version? As per requirement of PHPSpreadsheet it should work for PHP version 5.6 or newer.

Comment: As already said: check using the `phpinfo()` function. It will certainly show that the extension is _not_ enabled. Also check your http servers error log file when restarting it. Most likely it will tell you that it failed to enable the extension. Maybe a wrong path, maybe a wrong architecture, maybe compiled against the wrong php version...

Comment: @arkascha, I have verified using phpinfo() too and updated this information in question. phpinfo() shows that gd2 is enabled.

Comment: Please note that "gd" and "gd2" are two different things...

Comment: Okay, in that case even on the PC where only gd2 extension is enabled (PHP 5.6.35) and no gd it still works. on other PC where same configuration is there only difference is PHP version is 5.6.25 it is not working. Please help.

Comment: Sorry, I can't say any more. Maybe you need another version for the older php version? Is there any specific reason why you operate such vastly outdated php versions?

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem using **Wamp** local webserver on my Windows machine. My webserver loads PHP configuration from `/bin/php/php5.6.24/phpForApache.ini` (GD2 ext. loaded), but composer checks unused *official* `/bin/php/php5.6.24/php.ini` and there were only some default extensions loaded.

I know this is Wamp-dependent situation, but it could be it - server and composer reading different php.ini's.

Answer (score 0):

I have copied the "Vendor" folder created in my project folder by running composer successfully where PHP version is 5.6.35 to the project folder on the other machine where PHP version is 5.6.25 and able to use phpSpreadsheet.

Answer (score 0):

composer require "ext-gd:*" --ignore-platform-reqs

try this..

Answer (score 0):

Add extension=php_gd.dll to your php.ini file.